# Kendo Date to Date Time

Tags: html, css, angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am switching between a Kendo Date-Time picker and a Kendo Date Picker. The Picker alternates between the two depending on if the user has selected "All Day" - which then only the Date Picker is shown.

However, when switching from the Date-Picker, to the Date-Time picker, if one alters the date then tries to switch, Kendo doesn't store the date, and shows the Date-Time picker as empty.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label class=" control-label" for="start-date">Start Date & Time</label>
                    <input kendo-date-time-picker id="start-date-time" name="start-date-time"
                           data-ng-model="registeringUser.StartDate"
                           data-ng-required="true"
                           min="today"
                           max="howFarOut"
                           data-ng-show="!setAllDay">

                    <input kendo-date-picker id="start-date" name="start-date" 
                           data-ng-model="registeringUser.StartDate"
                           data-ng-required="true"
                           min="today"
                           max="howFarOut"
                           data-ng-show="setAllDay">

                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label class=" control-label" for="end-date">End Date & Time</label>
                    <input kendo-date-time-picker id="end-date-time" name="end-date-time"
                           data-ng-model="registeringUser.EndDate"
                           data-ng-required="true"
                           min="today"
                           max="howFarOut"
                           data-ng-show="!setAllDay">

                    <input kendo-date-picker id="end-date" name="end-date"
                           data-ng-model="registeringUser.EndDate"
                           data-ng-required="true"
                           min="today"
                           max="howFarOut"
                           data-ng-show="setAllDay">

                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
```

I currently switch between the option by changing the visibility, and it works as long as one does not alter the Date-Picker and then switches back to Date-Time. Does anyone know how to store the date when switching back to Date-Time?

For example: If it was 2/02/20002 3:00 PM, then when switched to Date only, it becomes 2/02/2002. But if I change the date to 2/03/2002, then switch it back to Date-Time, the calendar then reads as empty- while I'd like it to read as 2/03/2002 12:00 AM

```
scope.setAllDay = false;

                        scope.cbSelected = function () {
                            if (scope.myCheckbox) {  // when checked
                                scope.setAllDay = true;

                            } else {
                                scope.setAllDay = false;

                            }
                        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify kendo date time picker `parse-format` and match it with kendo date picker `format` by default its follow your `culture` setting, e.g `M/d/yyyy` for en-US

```
<input kendo-date-time-picker
       ng-model="dateString"
       k-ng-model="dateObject"
       k-parse-formats="['dd/MM/yyyy']"
       ng-show="!allDay"/>
<input kendo-date-picker id="start-date" name="start-date"
       k-format="dd/MM/yyyy"
       ng-model="dateString"
       ng-show="allDay">
```

See my [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EcAcu)